# How can map tags be used for two images that overlap?

Tags: html, css

We have two images with transparent sections that each have a map and separately they work fine. When the images are overlapped using css position relative and absolute only the top map seems to work. Is there some way to make both maps work?

Edit:
We are only concerned with working in Mozilla and the w3 standard so no IE workarounds are needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design. According to the HTML 4.01 spec, section 13.6.1 ("Client-side image maps: the MAP and AREA elements"):

> "If two or more defined regions
>   overlap, the region-defining element
>   that appears earliest in the document
>   takes precedence (i.e., responds to
>   user input)."

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.6.1)

**Note** for those who come hereafter looking for an answer to the same question: This answer does not address the issue of overlapping **images**. See the comments.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was "WHERE two or more defined regions overlap..." which would mean that if I have a large box that is mapped and it has a small box inside of it that is mapped then outside the small box the big box mapping would be used.

Comment: Wait ... so this means that if two regions overlap *anywhere*, then the second region-defining element doesn't respond to user input **at all** - even in the places that are not overlapped by the first? That isn't what I would expect "take precedence" to mean.

Comment: No, I don't this this answer is correct for the question. The OP is referring to multiple *images* (therefore separate image maps), whereas the spec quoted is just referring to multiple `<AREA>` elements within the same `<MAP>`. And what the spec says does **not** mean the second `<AREA>` won't respond to user input at all (which is what the OP was wrestling with). At least, the quoted text doesn't support that interpretation, and testing in Firefox/IE shows the second `<AREA>` responding to input outside of the overlap.

Comment: You can test this at http://www.huttar.net/tmp/test-overlaps.html. The pink `<area>` occurs first in the image map. By rolling the mouse over the rectangles and watching the status bar or the title tooltip, you can see that both areas respond to input (mouse location or click).